# How to install private npm package with yarn?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I need to install my company private npm packages with yarn - how do i do it?

I set the npm login auth token but it doesn't help - private npm packages always end up with errors like 404 not found etc.

```
yarn add @private/my-private-pacakge
```

doesn't work, but this npm command works:

```
npm install @private/my-private-package
```

works - I tried to set yarn config registry/auth with the token but noting helps.

Error:

```
Error: https://registry.npmjs.org/@private/my-private-package/-/my-private-package-0.0.5.tgz: Request failed "404 Not Found"
      at Request.res (/..../........./.yarn/updates/0.18.1/lib/fetchers/tarball-fetcher.js:231:20)
```

Comment: Did you set up your registry in the global .yarnrc? Can you share your yarn config?

Comment: @AndrésAndrade the problem was config issue - see my answer to my own question - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So my problem was with bad configuration I had strict-ssl config to false and registry config to http rather than https.

Comment: Could you elaborate to your answer to help reproduceability?

Comment: I believe he's referring to the "strict-ssl" and "registry" options in the .yarnrc file

Answer (score 0):

For future reference. What worked for me was to create an `.npmrc` file with the following contents:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

At first that did not work because the user `npm whoami` was not added to the team of the organisation (it was the owner of the organisation).

After I added the user to the team the package could be found with `npm` and `yarn`.